# VLC can't open RTSP stream on Google Compute Instance

Tags: azure, vlc, google-compute-engine, libvlc

I have a weird situation and I hope someone will be able to assist.
I'm using VLC (latest version) to open (pull) RTSP stream on Microsoft Azure (Windows 2012 R2). **The stream works great**.

When I'm using a Google compute instance with the same OS (Windows 2012 R2)and the same VLC player (same version) **the stream doesn't open and I'm getting 0 video blocks**.
Trying to open the same stream on Google Compute Instance with Windows 2008 R2 causes VLC to crash.

When I'm trying to open the same stream on various private machines (not on the cloud) the streams opens well.

I have no idea what could be the problem.
If I'm trying to isolate the problem I think the problem relates to Google Cloud network...but I might be wrong here...

Do you have any suggestion how to overcome this issue?

thanks,
R.

Comment: Check your firewall settings. By default, incoming connections to GCE instances are restricted for all but a few ports. See [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls) at GCE public documentation for more details. RSTP protocol uses port 1935 by default. Try opening that port for TCP and UDP on your server instance and let us know if it helps.

Comment: thanks. In this case I'm initiating the connection from GCE to the source and for other RTSP sources it works well. So I'm not sure this is the reason. I'll check this direction as well but I doubt that this is the issue.Any other directions you might have? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I spent a little bit of time setting up a similar environment and it all works **great**.

Here's what I would recommend checking:

1. Check that your GCE firewall allows for the right ports. (Which ever port you're streaming on.)
2. Disable or tweak the WINDOWS FIREWALL. If you're running on the standard Windows Server R2 image that Google provides, the Firewall is ON by DEFAULT and it will prevent you from accessing or running the stream. You can just open up your start menu and type in "Firewall" and then click on "**Windows Firewall**" to go disable it.
3. Try again!

If your stream is accessible from other machines and networks, then this is definitely a firewall problem.

I've tested the following:

- Running a VLC stream over RTSP on GCE's Windows R2 image. WORKS PERFECTLY.
- Connecting to an RTSP stream from VLC(Windows R2 GCE image). WORKS PERFECTLY.

In my case, the Windows Firewall was preventing me from streaming to external and to connect to my stream.